# Ursina isnt reconised by Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, ursina

So I have done `pip install ursina` in the command prompt but when I try write some code in visual studio code (like, `from ursina import *`) an error appears saying;

`No module named 'ursina'`

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

A common reason for this problem is that you have multiple versions of Python installed. Remove the old/unneeded ones. Then, in a command prompt, navigate to the Python installation location using the command `where python`, and then into the scripts folder and run `pip install ursina`

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, then please consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking on the tick mark beside the answer, and if it has been useful then please also consider upvoting by clicking on the up arrow :)

Answer (score 0):

IT HAS H
use this code;

from ursina import *

app= Ursina()

(code)

app.run()

use capital u in ursina